# SharePoint - Deploy new default.aspx through feature

Tags: development

I have created a feature which deploys a custom default.aspx page. The deployed file goes to the template\features{featureName} directory.

How does SharePoint know to use this default.aspx page instead of the one that is located in SiteTemplates{Site Def name} directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that a Publishing site? if yes then you can write a module element to upload this default page on SharePoint Pages library and overwrite the preexisting one. You may need to write feature receiver to overwrite the existing file or you can refer my blog to overwrite files using SharePoint module element.
http://vivek-soni.blogspot.com/2009/07/overwriting-files-using-module-element.html

Comment: This is a very good article no doubt.  This issue however is that the feature is stapled to a site definition.  In the sequence of operations the features run before the provisioning process has an opportunity to put the default.aspx page in place.  As such, it is not possible to get a reference to the default.aspx which is delivered with the site definition.

Comment: I can deploy a customDefault.aspx page but i cannot have it replace the default.aspx as it doesn't exist yet in the sequence of operations.
I can however deploy a page called default.aspx.  My issue is when I go to deactivate the page, how can I get a reference to the site definition original default.aspx? (as mentioned i cannot get a reference to it in my feature as it doesnt exist yet).
thx

Comment: In that case you can write a custom site provisioning handler that would run after your site hasbeen provisioned completely.
Now this provisioning handler could either activate another feature that has a new default.aspx page or you could write the code to manually delete the default.aspx and upload a new one.

Comment: Do you mean, an external application that provisions the site and once the site has been created(finished) activate another feature OR from within replace the default.aspx page?

Comment: Yes refer this http://www.sharepointdev.net/sharepoint--development-programming/spwebprovisioningprovider-site-branding-57083.shtml
on how we can use SPWebProvisioningProvider